# SIP dialog CSeq sequence number

Tags: dialog, sequence, sip

I'm trying to make sense of the following two RFC sections with respect to SIP dialogs and incrementing CSeq sequence numbers:

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-12.2.1.1

https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3261#section-12.2.2

The first RFC section says that, with respect to a UAC,

> Requests within a dialog MUST contain strictly monotonically increasing and contiguous CSeq sequence numbers (increasing-by-one) in each direction.

However the latter sections states that with respect to a UAS,

> It is possible for the CSeq sequence number to be higher than the remote sequence number by more than one.  This is not an error condition, and a UAS SHOULD be prepared to receive and process requests with CSeq values more than one higher than the previous received request.

In my scenario, I have a device sending a SIP subscribe to a server. The server can then send zero or more notify request's within the same dialog to that subscriber. Can the server sending the notify's increment the CSeq sequence number by more than one without the subscriber rejecting the request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. In the real World you're not going to find a SIP user agent rejecting a request due to a CSeq that's skipped a few numbers in the sequence.

Request will get rejected if the CSeq is less than or equal to the CSeq in a previous request as they will get classified as re-transmits.

Comment: What happens when the device resubscribes? The call ID, from, and to headers should be the same correct? But is the sequence number incremented in a resubscribe?

Comment: You'd have to check the RFC for that one (RFC 3265 I think). I would have guessed that re-subscribing would generate a new dialog and would therefore use different values for the Call-ID, From and To tags and other transaction related headers.

Comment: So according to the RFC a UAC needs to increment the sequence number for each request, but what doesn't make sense to me is if a resubscribe is in-flight with a new sequence number (which has not yet reached the UAS), and a request within the same dialog is in-flight to the UAC, also with the same number, then wouldn't the UAC reject the new request?

Comment: I have a comment on the top of my own SIPDialogue class (https://github.com/sipsorcery/sipsorcery/blob/master/sipsorcery-core/SIPSorcery.SIP.Core/SIP/SIPDialogue.cs) where I noted that two CSeq's need to be maintained, one each for the UAC and UAS. Unfortunately I can't find exactly where in RFC3261 I got that from but I suspect it's in there somewhere.